# How to add user's full name and profile picture on logined user of firebase using android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am written code for Firebase mobile authentication with OTP but I want to add in that users name filed and users profile picture upload section but I don't know to do it? I tried to find everywhere but not found which I found was for email-passward authentication not for mobile OTP authentication can anyone tell me how to add user's Full Name and and User profile picture in firebase and retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the account is created, you can [update the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) by calling `user.updateProfile`. From that link:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add firebase real-time database/ Firebase Firestore and Firebase Storage api in your project.
And on time of signup

1. add fileds of name and profile picture
2. Upload picture to your firebase storage and copy its link.
3. Add name and picture link in your database

and activity where you need to retrieve data
use Glide lib to load image
and retrieve name also